# What parts can you upgrade on a MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, upgrade

If I buy a MacBook Pro, what parts can I upgrade later?

Is it possible to upgrade to more memory? Is it possible to upgrade to another harddrive? e.g. to a newer SSD-drive? Anything else that is possible to upgrade?

Comment: Are you asking a general question about all MBP's or only about the new models of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how much you care about your warranty.

If you want to keep your warranty valid, Apple says you can upgrade your hard drive and your RAM—and that's all.

To learn how to do it, here are Apple's user manuals and page references for the current (mid-2010) MacBook Pros:

- [13" (pages 37-48)](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/MacBook_Pro_13inch_Mid2010.pdf)
- [15" (pages 37-48)](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/MacBook_Pro_15inch_Mid2010.pdf)
- [17" (pages 37-49)](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/MacBook_Pro_17inch_Mid2010.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Am1rr3za's answers (other than the CPU, which is soldered to the logic board), you can also convert the optical drive bay to a caddy which houses a second hard drive or solid state drive.  This is a huge upgrade if you can stand being without an internal disc drive...

Comment: Does that void the warranty?

Comment: Not if you don't break anything, are careful not to strip screws or remove stickers, and put the optical drive back in before you take it back in for service :)  Who really knows what actually voids an Apple warranty?  They seem to evaluate it on a case by case basis (or based on what "genius" happens to be working that day).  I say don't worry about it, be careful, and do what you want with the product you paid upwards of one thousand dollars for.  If you bark loud enough later and haven't filled the case with vaseline, they'll honor your warranty.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can upgrade some parts of your MacBook Pro:

1. [Upgrade your hard drive](https://www.extremetech.com/computing/58220-upgrade-your-macbook-pros-hard-drive-2).
2. [Upgrade to more memory](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/faq/macbook-pro-ram-installation-instructions.html).
3. You can also upgrade CPU and WiFi Card.
4. You won't be able to upgrade the graphics card on the MBP. It's soldered onto the motherboard.

Comment: you can't upgrade your CPU without some serious skillz... it's also soldered onto the logic board.

Comment: Upgrading the CPU is about just as hard as upgrading the graphics card. Which means, not possible.